# Using XSLT muenchian grouping to calculate sports team standings (wins/losses)?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping, muenchian-grouping

I have been struggling for days to determine how to take an XML file of game results (teams and final scores) and generate a team standings list that shows each team along with how many times they won, lost or tied. The results should also be sorted by total wins, but I can't even figure out a good method of calculating the wins/losses let alone sorting by the results. I know it must involve muenchian grouping, and I've coded the part that finds all distinct teams but am stumped where to go from there. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

**games.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="games.xsl"?>

<Games>

  <Game>
    <Home>Team A</Home>
    <Away>Team B</Away>
    <Home_Score>20</Home_Score>
    <Away_Score>15</Away_Score>
  </Game>

  <Game>
    <Home>Team C</Home>
    <Away>Team D</Away>
    <Home_Score>12</Home_Score>
    <Away_Score>18</Away_Score>
  </Game>

  <Game>
    <Home>Team A</Home>
    <Away>Team C</Away>
    <Home_Score>8</Home_Score>
    <Away_Score>8</Away_Score>
  </Game>

  <Game>
    <Home>Team B</Home>
    <Away>Team D</Away>
    <Home_Score>6</Home_Score>
    <Away_Score>14</Away_Score>
  </Game>

  <Game>
    <Home>Team D</Home>
    <Away>Team C</Away>
    <Home_Score>9</Home_Score>
    <Away_Score>11</Away_Score>
  </Game>

  <Game>
    <Home>Team C</Home>
    <Away>Team A</Away>
    <Home_Score>13</Home_Score>
    <Away_Score>13</Away_Score>
  </Game>

</Games>
```

**games.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- Key for identifying teams -->
  <xsl:key name="unique-teams" match="/Games/Game" use="Home" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Team Standings</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Get distinct teams, sort by team name -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Game[generate-id() = generate-id(key('unique-teams', Home)[1])]">
            <xsl:sort select="Home" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>

    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Game">

    <!-- Current team -->
    <xsl:variable name="selectedteam" select="Home" />

    <!-- Output each unique team name to the screen -->
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="$selectedteam"/></h1>

    <!-- Loop through all games to calculate totals??? -->
    <xsl:for-each select="//Game">    
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sam J., Was my answer useful to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You want something like this (XSLT 1.0):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kTeamByName" match="Home|Away" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">

 <table border="1">
  <tr>
   <td>Team</td><td>W</td><td>D</td><td>L</td>
  </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=
      "(*/Home | */Away)
        [generate-id()
        =
         generate-id(key('kTeamByName', .)[1])
        ]
      ">
      <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="descending" select=
       "count(key('kTeamByName', .)
                 [self::Home
                and
                  ../Home_Score > ../Away_Score
                or
                  self::Away
                and
                  ../Away_Score > ../Home_Score
                 ]
             )
       "/>

      </xsl:apply-templates>
  </table>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Home|Away">
  <tr>
   <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </td>
   <td>
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "count(key('kTeamByName', .)
                 [self::Home
                and
                  ../Home_Score > ../Away_Score
                or
                  self::Away
                and
                  ../Away_Score > ../Home_Score
                 ]
             )"/>
   </td>
   <td>
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "count(key('kTeamByName', .)
                 [../Home_Score = ../Away_Score]
             )"/>
   </td>
   <td>
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "count(key('kTeamByName', .)
                 [self::Home
                and
                  ../Away_Score > ../Home_Score
                or
                  self::Away
                and
                  ../Home_Score > ../Away_Score
                 ]
             )"/>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Games>
    <Game>
        <Home>Team A</Home>
        <Away>Team B</Away>
        <Home_Score>20</Home_Score>
        <Away_Score>15</Away_Score>
    </Game>
    <Game>
        <Home>Team C</Home>
        <Away>Team D</Away>
        <Home_Score>12</Home_Score>
        <Away_Score>18</Away_Score>
    </Game>
    <Game>
        <Home>Team A</Home>
        <Away>Team C</Away>
        <Home_Score>8</Home_Score>
        <Away_Score>8</Away_Score>
    </Game>
    <Game>
        <Home>Team B</Home>
        <Away>Team D</Away>
        <Home_Score>6</Home_Score>
        <Away_Score>14</Away_Score>
    </Game>
    <Game>
        <Home>Team D</Home>
        <Away>Team C</Away>
        <Home_Score>9</Home_Score>
        <Away_Score>11</Away_Score>
    </Game>
    <Game>
        <Home>Team C</Home>
        <Away>Team A</Away>
        <Home_Score>13</Home_Score>
        <Away_Score>13</Away_Score>
    </Game>
</Games>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>Team</td>
      <td>W</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>L</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Team D</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Team A</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Team C</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Team B</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you so much for the complete example. XSL is still very foreign to me compared to any other language I've used, so I appreciate the help and was able to follow how your code works.